# where can I find equivalent of 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\' on OS X?

Tags: macos, java

I need to place two jar files in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\` but I am on OS X.

Any idea where I can find the right directory? It's not in /Applications/Utilities

Comment: it was `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/lib/security
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but it's probably `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/security/` or somewhere similar.